# While fetching details using GET request, 401 error returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, newrelic, synthetic

I am trying to generate employee details by enabling a synthetic API monitor in Newrelic based on NODEJS. I have successfully generated an access token in first POST request but the second one is failing. This works on Postman.

While validating, I am getting following error

> Error : "401 UnAuthorized to access the resource."

Below is the code.

```
var info,token;
var assert = require('assert');
var options = 
{
  uri: '***',
  body: '***',
  headers: {
            'access_key': '***',
            'client_credentials': '***',
            'Content-Type': '***'
           }
}
$http.post(options,function (err, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
     info = JSON.parse(body);
     token=info.access_token;
  console.log("Security token retrieved successfully");
  console.log(token);
  assert.ok(response.statusCode == 200, 'Expected 200 response'); 
  }
);
var options2 = 
{
  uri: '***',
  headers: {
            'access_key': '***',
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }      
}
$http.get(options2,function (err, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
        assert.ok(response.statusCode == 200, 'Expected 200 response'); 
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by cascading first call's response with second request due to Async nature.